# Azure Data Factory Python SDK Create Trigger

Tags: python, azure, azure-data-factory

I'm working with the Azure Data Factory Python SDK to create a Trigger as documented [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/how-to-create-schedule-trigger?tabs=data-factory#python-sdk). Unfortunately, it's not working and I'm getting a very cryptic error message.

I'm using the following code (as per the example):

```py
tr_name = 'mytrigger'
scheduler_recurrence = ScheduleTriggerRecurrence(frequency='Minute', interval='15',start_time='2017-12-12T04:00:00Z', end_time='2017-12-12T05:00:00Z', time_zone='UTC')
pipeline_parameters = {'inputPath':'adftutorial/input', 'outputPath':'adftutorial/output'}
pipelines_to_run = []
pipeline_reference = PipelineReference(reference_name='copyPipeline')
pipelines_to_run.append(TriggerPipelineReference(pipeline_reference=pipeline_reference, parameters=pipeline_parameters))
tr_properties = ScheduleTrigger(description='My scheduler trigger', pipelines = pipelines_to_run, recurrence=scheduler_recurrence)


adf_client.triggers.create_or_update(rg_name, df_name, tr_name, tr_properties)
```

The error I'm getting is:

```
azure.core.exceptions.HttpResponseError: (InvalidPropertyValue) Invalid value for property 'Properties'
Code: InvalidPropertyValue
Message: Invalid value for property 'Properties'
Target: mytrigger
```

which doesn't tell me much at all :-(. Has anyone seen this before? I'm struggling to figure this out. I've looked for an attribute `Properties`, but there doesn't seem to be one. Is there a good way to debug what's going on here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To resolve this `azure.core.exceptions.HttpResponseError: (InvalidPropertyValue) Invalid value for property 'Properties'` error:

Instead of:

```
tr_properties = ScheduleTrigger(description='My scheduler trigger', pipelines = pipelines_to_run, recurrence=scheduler_recurrence)
```

You can try this:

```
tr_properties = TriggerResource(properties=ScheduleTrigger(description='My scheduler trigger',pipelines=pipelines_to_run,recurrence=scheduler_recurrence))
```

You can refer to [Bad body serialization creating a Schedule Trigger in Data Factory](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-python/issues/18905) and [Azure data factory trigger creation using python SDK](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-python/issues/20664)